# C#: Media player controls (Trackbar / Sliders / ..)

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, media, trackbar

i'm currently porting a media player delphi application to C# and therefore i need some advanced controls for winforms. In fact they should give me the possiblity to create such a style:

Trackbar:

[Trackbar: http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/5345/trackbar.jpg](http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/5345/trackbar.jpg)

The full background (including the markers) is a image, also the slider itself.

Trackbar2:

[Slider: http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/3193/trackbar2.jpg](http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/3193/trackbar2.jpg)

Nothing special here, just something like the normal trackbar control but some advanced possiblites for setting style.

In fact i'm looking for a package like this http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tiw.asp but for C# winforms.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/#main|controls